# Android Studio javax.mail jar build error

Tags: android, email

I'm trying to use the Gmail API to send emails. I've followed the Google documentation on how to do this. I need access to MimeMessage which is from the import:

`javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;`

Since this is not included by default in Android Studio I downloaded the .jar files and did.

File -> New -> New Module -> Import .JAR

I also physically placed the javax.jar in the libs folder in Android Studio and referenced the jar from there.

my build.gradle(app) file looks like this in the dependencies section:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.20.0'
    compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.20.0'
    compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client-gson:1.20.0'
    compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-gmail:v1-rev29-1.20.0'
    compile project(':javax.mail')
}
```

However when I clean and build the project I get this error:

`com.android.ide.common.ProcessException: org.gradle.Internal.ExecException.`

I googled this and I'm pretty sure it has to do with my .jar file reference but I'm not sure how to fix this.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Add this to your dependencies section:

```
compile  'javax.mail:javax.mail-api:1.5.3'
```

Comment: ok great.... some tutorial page please....as a reference for this version of javax.mail-api. for adding more upvote. :D

Answer (score 5):

They now have a library built just for Android, which you can find here:
https://javaee.github.io/javamail/Android

There are two libraries available as of right now.
You probably only need the first.

```
implementation 'com.sun.mail:android-mail:1.6.0'
implementation 'com.sun.mail:android-activation:1.6.0'
```

Note: `implementation` is just the new standard for `compile`

Comment: Does the `javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;` import stay the same?

Comment: how about additional.jar?

Answer (score 2):

Add this to dependency in your **build.gradle** (Module: app)

```
    implementation  'javax.mail:javax.mail-api:1.5.3'
```

Comment: this work for android studio 4.2.2 +1

Answer (score 0):

Android Studio Giraffe  built from August 17 2023

I had very similar problem related to it and people might have this problem finding this topic

I couldn't import the javax.mail.... as the IDE wasn't aware of the build config

Navigate to File > Project Structure > Dependencies.

seems like my reference was outdated, updated using this view and now I can compile

now my Build.gradle has this line:

implementation("javax.mail:javax.mail-api:1.6.2")

Answer (score 0):

This library work for me
implementation 'com.sun.mail:android-mail:1.6.0'

I also use this class as helper for sending email.

```
public class GMailClient extends Authenticator {
private final Session mailSession;
private final String mailUser;
private final String password;

public GMailClient(String mailUser, String password) {
    this.mailUser = mailUser;
    this.password = password;

    Properties properties = System.getProperties();
    properties.setProperty(MailServerSettings.SMTP_HOST, GmailServerSettings.smtpHost);
    properties.setProperty(MailServerSettings.SMTP_PORT, "465");
    properties.setProperty(MailServerSettings.SMTP_AUTH, "true");
    properties.setProperty(MailServerSettings.SMTP_STARTTLS, "true");
    properties.setProperty(MailServerSettings.SMTP_SOCKET_FACTORY_PORT, "465");
    properties.setProperty(MailServerSettings.SMTP_SOCKET_FACTORY_CLASS, "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
    properties.setProperty(MailServerSettings.IMAP_HOST, GmailServerSettings.imapHost);
    properties.setProperty(MailServerSettings.IMAP_PORT, "993");
    properties.setProperty(MailServerSettings.IMAP_AUTH, "true");
    properties.setProperty(MailServerSettings.IMAP_STARTTLS, "true");
    properties.setProperty(MailServerSettings.IMAP_SOCKET_FACTORY_PORT, "993");
    properties.setProperty(MailServerSettings.IMAP_SOCKET_FACTORY_CLASS, "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
    properties.setProperty(MailServerSettings.IMAP_STORE_PROTOCOL, "imap");
    properties.setProperty(MailServerSettings.IMAP_SOCKET_FACTORY_FALLBACK, "false");

    mailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties, this);
}

public MimeMessage createEmailMessage(String emailSubject, File attachment) throws MessagingException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
    MimeMessage emailMessage = new MimeMessage(this.mailSession);
    String str = this.mailUser;
    emailMessage.setFrom(new InternetAddress(str, str));
    emailMessage.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress("littleball.cuba@gmail.com"));
    emailMessage.setSubject(emailSubject);
    Multipart mp = new MimeMultipart();
    MimeBodyPart part = new MimeBodyPart();
    part.setFileName(attachment.getName());
    part.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(new ByteArrayDataSource(readFile(attachment), "application/octet-stream")));
    mp.addBodyPart(part);
    emailMessage.setContent(mp);
    return emailMessage;
}

public byte[] readFile(File file) {
    try {
        FileInputStream istream = new FileInputStream(file);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[((int) file.length())];
        istream.read(buffer);
        return buffer;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }
}

public void sendEmail(Message msg) throws MessagingException {
    Transport transport = this.mailSession.getTransport("smtp");
    transport.connect(GmailServerSettings.smtpHost, this.mailUser, this.password);
    transport.sendMessage(msg, msg.getAllRecipients());
    transport.close();
}

public Message[] getEmail() throws MessagingException {
    Store store = this.mailSession.getStore("imap");
    store.connect(GmailServerSettings.imapHost, this.mailUser, this.password);
    Folder inbox = store.getFolder(MailFolders.INBOX);
    inbox.open(1);
    return inbox.getMessages();
}

public Folder getInboxFolder() throws MessagingException {
    Store store = this.mailSession.getStore("imap");
    store.connect(GmailServerSettings.imapHost, this.mailUser, this.password);
    Folder inbox = store.getFolder(MailFolders.INBOX);
    inbox.open(2);
    return inbox;
}

public void closeFolder(Folder inbox) throws MessagingException {
    inbox.close(true);
}

public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
    return new PasswordAuthentication(this.mailUser, this.password);
}}

public interface GmailServerSettings {
String imapAuth = "true";
String imapHost = "imap.gmail.com";
String imapPort = "993";
String imapProtocol = "imap";
String imapSocketFactoryFallback = "false";
String imapSocketFactoryPort = "993";
String imapSslSocketFactoryClass = "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory";
String imapStartTls = "true";
String smtpAuth = "true";
String smtpHost = "smtp.gmail.com";
String smtpPort = "465";
String smtpProtocol = "smtp";
String smtpSocketFactoryPort = "465";
String smtpSslSocketFactoryClass = "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory";
String smtpStartTls = "true";}
```